# Find certain words in comment posts

Tags: sql

I'm trying to prune out a lot of spam posts I keep getting in the guestbook on our website as the Capture doesn't seem to be working very well at preventing such posts. What I'm trying to do is to just use *phpmyadmin* to run something like:

```
SELECT * FROM GUESTBOOK WHERE "MY COLUMN NAME" CONTAINS "WORD"
```

or something similar, but I'm not sure how you do this in mysql. I can then just delete all those posts once selected.

So I'm basically trying to look in the text string stored and see if it contains a certain word and then select it if it does.

Comment: I've seen the following trick work well: You put a visible checkbox there, which says "I'm not a bot". Bots generally don't check them. And secondly, you add an invisible checkbox ("I'm a bot"), and only accept the entry if it stays unchecked. Some clever bots click all checkboxes, including the invisible ones.

Comment: Since Kajetan is talking about prevention here. Iain, you could try to check the value for words like these before inserting them into the database. In case of `PHP` with a function like `preg_match()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `LIKE` operator for SQL [supports](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) what you're trying to do:

```
SELECT * FROM GUESTBOOK WHERE `MY COLUMN NAME` LIKE "%WORD%"
```

**Note**: notice I've changed " to ` in the query.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to do:

```
SELECT * FROM GUESTBOOK WHERE GUESTBOOK.`MY COLUMN NAME` LIKE '%word%' COLLATE utf_general_ci
```

To avoid case sensitivity issues.